# Composer google oauth svn repository

Tags: php, composer-php, google-oauth

i'm trying to install google outh2 with composer using this json

```
    {
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "oauth-php/oauth-php",
                "version": "175",
                "source": {
                    "type": "svn",
                    "url": "http://oauth-php.googlecode.com/svn",
                    "reference": "trunk/"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["library/"]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "oauth-php/oauth-php": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["include/"]
    }
}
```

But i retrieve this message

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing oauth-php/oauth-php (175)
    Checking out trunk/

[RuntimeException]
  Package could not be downloaded, "svn" it not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv
|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

Where am i wrong?
Thanks,
Leandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "svn" it not recognized as an internal or external command

You must install subversion to download the package

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#git-alternatives:

> To get packages from these systems you need to have their respective clients installed. That can be inconvenient.